# Is it better to have separate projects for Storefront and backend or single?

Tags: java, api, web-applications, architecture

I am running an ecommerce website built in Java using Spring and Hibernate. If I have to briefly describe current architecture then it is like this:

1. Two projects - **store front** and **admin**
2. **Storefront** project holds dao, model, service, controller and views for showing the storefront view of website and also hold APIs for apps
3. **Admin** project holds dao, model, service, controller and views for showing the backend/admin interfaces for managing this ecommerce store.
4. Storefront and admin both independently talk with common MySQL database and whenever any communication is required between these two projects, they do that using REST APIs.
5. I Followed this architecture to develop both projects independently, keep them light, and deploy them independently.

But I am not really sure that this is the correct way of doing things. Major problems that I frequently face are:

1. It generally causes code duplicacy, mostly in Models, as it is something both projects have but most properties in them are common.
2. If any changes in database required, then I have to make sure those changes are properly made in both projects as both are making independent DB calls.

Please suggest what could be the best approach for handling and architecting such project. Website stats are:

1. Around 1 million products
2. Monthly traffic around 1 million
3. Per day orders around 1000

And we are looking for more growth in traffic and orders, in next 9 months. So please suggest keeping future scalability in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Shared Common Model:** With regards to common model shared across the applications that may grow & prone to frequent changes, you can make the model a separate project having its pom dependency in each of the projects. Even better is to keep that project with json schema definition and have maven plugin (assuming you are using maven) to convert them to POJOs during the build and add to your project classpath. Please refer [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

**Website stats/traffic growth:** For this please consider load-balance clustering (if you have not done) your web/application server adding multiple nodes. This will help in high availability of your application and handle heavy traffic.

There may be other better solutions, but these points are worth considering. I have some thoughts on your other points but I feel there could be better solutions with others who have better knowledge of architecture.

Hope these thoughts help.

Comment: I was expecting more responses, but none are there. I liked your idea about shared common model. Could you please share any more ideas related to better project structuring.
I have decent knowledge related to handling traffic growth. But creating a structured and maintainable project is something I can't find any resource over internet.